# Java - Issues parsing a string for a simple calculator program

Tags: java

I have code that takes input and then figures out what you are wanting to do with it

eg. You would type in "x (+,-,..etc) y" and it would calculate it for you.

Im currently using a Scanner and splitting it up such that

```
double x = input.nextDouble();
String z = input.next();
double y = input.nextDouble();
```

Now I have run into a problem. Say I want to do a factorial I would then input "x !" but the code is still wanting the last input.nextDouble();

How would I go about (using what I am doing, if possible) checking to see if all 3 have inputs and then selecting between the methods using an if statement or if only 2 have inputs.

Relative code

```
System.out.print("> ");
double x = input.nextInt();
String z = input.next();
double y = input.nextInt();

if (x == 0) {
running = false;

} else if (z.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {

    System.out.println(addition(x, y));

}
```

Comment: You can check whether the operator is unary or binary operator. If operator works on single operand then take single input. If operator is binary then take two inputs. You will have to check operator which user want to do..then take inputs.Hope it helps u.

Comment: Why 0 is not valid first argument?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of getting three different inputs, just input a single line of string, parse the string accordingly and type cast them to the necessary types. This way you can determine from the string is a factorial (1 variable) or any other operation on it is necessary.

Using scanner.

```
            boolean binary = true;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double x = input.nextInt();
    String z = input.next();
    //check if z is a unary operator ie. 
            if(z=='!')
                binary = true;
    if(binary)
        double y = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: How is it better than Scanner?

Comment: The problem is not with using scanner, you could just use any reader. The problem the OP had was that he needed a solution to operate on both Unary ans Binary operators. The solution provided is not specific or limited to Scanner.

Comment: I agree with you, but OP also mentioned "(using what I am doing, if possible)".

Comment: I should have missed that, yeah you can do the same thing with scanner, infact scanner would be better because of the particular overhead in the typecast. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two inputs, then your code will throw `NoSuchElementException`. To avoid that you should use `input.hasNext()`.

```
double x = input.nextInt();
String z = input.next();

if (input.hasNext()) {
    // input has y
    y = input.nextInt();
    // perform operation on two elements
} else {
    // no y
    // perform operation on one element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra if statement and ask for 'y' only if z = '+'.

```
System.out.print("> ");
double x = input.nextInt();
String z = input.next();


if (x == 0) {
running = false;

} else if(z.equalsIgnoreCase("!")){
     factorial(x);
}
else if (z.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
double y = input.nextInt();
System.out.println(addition(x, y));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
   double y = 0.0;
    if(!z.contains("!")){
     y = sc.nextDouble();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must get the input as a string so you must use `String.indexof()` and divide the main string in two string you must `parse` the first part like this:

```
  int a=Integer.parse(someString);
```

and the second part of your string would show you what you must to do with that.